# Mapbox Store Locater, links are not working

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm new at mapbox. So, I'm learning how to do a store locator by this tutorial
https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/

I'm stacked in "Make the map interactive" section. Up to here, everything is ok.
It works fine, the problem is when user clicks on links(list) which are in sidebar, nothing happens. However, it should go the specific location on map.

Here is the whole file. Please, help. I don't know where it goes wrong.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wj04pyjguh0j7a/index.html?dl=0

Comment: The tutorial is working as expected for me. Are you sure you're clicking on the dark green link in the sidebar? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @mollymerp thank you. I reviewed it, and solved the problem.  I have another issue, with "Locate the user" function, it doesn't work in chrome.but work in firefox. can you help, please.  you can check it here: http://store-locator.businesscatalyst.com/